# How to use symfony environments dev and prod

Tags: php, apache, symfony

This may seem a dumb question, I need my symfony 3 app to behave different in production than it does in my local machine. I know there is an entry point for each env, app.php and app_dev.php

I don't want to change the application web/.htaccess file because it's followed by git, I was expecting an 'env' var or something similar in app/config.yml but there is also a config.yml and a config_dev.yml, so it has to be another place where I can define if I am working with prod or dev env.

Documentation says that I need to setup my apache server to use either web/app.php or web/app_dev.php, and this is my question. I'm using apache 2.4 and I tried using the following directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    <directory>
        ...
        DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I restarted apache, but when I type `localhost:8000` in my browser, it keeps using the default app.php, I need my apache server to use app_dev.php, I don't want to use the built-in server because it gets buggy after a while.

Can anyone please help me with the apache configuration to use the dev env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the following problems: regardless of which `DirectoryIndex` you define, the server also picks ups some settings from `.htaccess`. Could it be possible that you have another reference to `app.php` in there, like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]`?

Then you could do the following: move that exact setting from `.htaccess` to your server configuration, both locally and on the production server. Then you can keep all other settings independent from your enviroment.

If this does not help yet, please share the content of `.htaccess`.

Another way of solving could be to use a recent Symfony version and put everything that might change between environments in the `.env` file. Don't put it under version control, as this file might contain sensitive information. Then have a look at the current basics: you no longer have a `app.php` and `app_dev.php`, as the changes were only little. A common `index.php` is used, and it reads all current settings from `.env`

Comment: Thanks! I copied the symfonyapp/web/.htaccess configuration to my site.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-availables/, also modifying the 'app.php' to 'app_dev.php' and it works in dev environment now